# How to compile all files in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

I have bunch of file in my project that show up in the navigator, but Xcode does not compile them, so I get a link error when I try to build.

How do I get Xcode to build every file in my project?

Comment: Add them to your target -- "get info" on each file and select the appropriate target.  (Note: Don't add H files.)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your target is including the files when compiling.  You can do this by selecting the target and going to Build Phases and then Compile Sources.

Comment: Is there any way to just add all the files in my project to that list?

Comment: If you click on the '+' at the bottom of Compile Sources, you should be able to select multiple files from there by holding down shift or command when selecting.

Comment: both targets are showing all the m and cpp files on the compile sources list

Comment: in the file list and under "Prodcts" is shows libqrencode.a and QRCodeEncodeDemo.app in red, when I compile it builds the libqrencode.a but the app is still red